# How to configure local smtp server in SharePoint 3.0?

Tags: sharepoint, smtp, wss-3.0

I,m trying to configure WSS 3.0 to use my local smtp server on IIS.
When I'm testing smtp server using telnet it returns message that w-mail is queued to send but e-mail are supplied to their destination.

SPUtilit send mail dosen't work for me. I suspect that the name of smtp server in central administration configuration is wrong. I passed there host name, because nothing else were accepted.

Can anybody help me?

log:

02/13/2010 00:43:18.02  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x12F4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8l3c    Medium      Localized resource for token 'DistributionLists_Alias' could not be found for file with path: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\xml\base.xml".
02/13/2010 00:43:26.94  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          8gsj    Critical    An error occurred while talking to SMTP host 楳癬牥〲〱b�ӹ.
02/13/2010 00:43:26.96  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          8gsf    High        #160003: Błąd odczytu z hosta SMTP 'silver2010b'.
02/13/2010 00:43:26.96  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8kh7    High        Nie można ukończyć tej akcji.  Spróbuj ponownie.
02/13/2010 00:43:26.97  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          7946    Critical    Nie można ukończyć tej akcji.  Spróbuj ponownie.
02/13/2010 00:44:10.55  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          8gsj    Critical    An error occurred while talking to SMTP host 楳癬牥〲〱b�ӹ.
02/13/2010 00:44:10.56  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          8gsf    High        #160003: Błąd odczytu z hosta SMTP 'silver2010b'.
02/13/2010 00:44:10.56  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8kh7    High        Nie można ukończyć tej akcji.  Spróbuj ponownie.
02/13/2010 00:44:10.56  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          7946    Critical    Nie można ukończyć tej akcji.  Spróbuj ponownie.
02/13/2010 00:44:14.44  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          8gsj    Critical    An error occurred while talking to SMTP host 楳癬牥〲〱b�ӹ.
02/13/2010 00:44:14.44  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          8gsf    High        #160003: Błąd odczytu z hosta SMTP 'silver2010b'.
02/13/2010 00:44:14.44  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8kh7    High        Nie można ukończyć tej akcji.  Spróbuj ponownie.
02/13/2010 00:44:14.44  w3wp.exe (0x1238)                           0x0F94  Windows SharePoint Services     E-Mail                          7946    Critical    Nie można ukończyć tej akcji.  Spróbuj ponownie.
02/13/2010 00:45:09.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0808)                       0x0A88  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Entering MRU trim routine.
02/13/2010 00:45:09.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0808)                       0x0A88  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Initial table size: 0 in 0 entries
02/13/2010 00:45:09.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0808)                       0x0A88  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Final table size: 0 in 0 entries
02/13/2010 00:45:09.78  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0808)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257488/smtp-configuration-to-work-with-sharepoint-3-0-how-to/2257743 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with SMTP configuration. When you open IIS6 configuration of SMTP server, then open server propertis and go to the Access tab, you can see there tow buttons.

1)connection
and
2)relay

Just put there your host name and problem is solved. :)